# Powershell, InternetExplorer.Application and Windows 11 (deleted IE)

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Working code in Windows 10 with IE

```
    $mod_nums = @(19, 22)
    $oIE = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $my_arr = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    foreach ($mod_num in $mod_nums) {
        if ($null -eq $mod_num) {
            break
        }
        $oIE.Navigate("https://wgmods.net/" + "$mod_num")
        
        for ($i = 0; $i -le 5; $i++) {
            do {
                Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            } until ((-not $oIE.Busy) -and ($oIE.ReadyState -eq $READYSTATE_COMPLETE))
        }
        
        $oDocument = $oIE.Document
        $oHtmlElement = $oDocument.GetElementsByClassName("ModDetails_hidden--2Rtru")[0]
        
        $a = "$($oHtmlElement.href)"
        
        $my_arr += $a
    }
```

BUT in windows 11 IE deleted and $oIE.Navigate just open new window in Edge. Events, Methods, Properties dont work. Trying set IE mode in Edge - nothing changes.

Invoke-WebRequest is not suitable bec wgmods.net checks browser

Interested in any ideas about this. tnx!

Answer (score 1):

IE is discontinued in Windows 11 and it's not expected that the old COM objects will continue to function. Per [Internet Explorer mode and the DevTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/#replacing-internet-explorer-automation):

> If you have an existing application that uses the InternetExplorer object to automate Internet Explorer 11, but the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application isn't available, your application won't work. Internet Explorer 11 will be retired on June 15, 2022.

Despite the date however, Windows 11 does not have IE baked in so IE-specific automation won't work. The solution as mentioned in the same document above is to use the [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752040(v=vs.85)) control to drive browser automation, which looks to include the IE mode use case:

> Applications that require IE mode for the website (or app) content to function correctly should use the `WebBrowser` control. The `WebBrowser` control uses the Internet Explorer platform (MSHTML/Trident) to render web content, and will work even if the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application isn't available.

The good news is you have a few months until Windows 11 is released to get your automation updated, plus however long it takes for you to start using it in your environment.