# IE not returning Document Values

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me determine the reason why my document values below are returning as null?   And more importantly how to get the values populated?    I am running with the latest Windows 11 and installed powershell

```
  $targetUrl = "https://www.tigerrunresort.com/vacation-rentals-homes-search.asp? 
txtStartDate=8%2F1%2F2022&txtEndDate=8%2F7%2F2022&categoryid=11317&destinationID=0&communityID=0&amenBedrooms=-1&maxPersons=0&advs=&sort=0&currentPage=1&flexibleDates=0&flexibleDatesThreshold=&searchAmenities=&showOnlySpecials=0"

   $ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
   $ie.visible=$true
   $ie.navigate($targetUrl)
   
   while($ie.Busy -or ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4)) {
        Start-Sleep -m 3000
   }
   $ie.Document.Body.innerHTML
   $output = $ie.document.
   $output.GetType()
   
   if($output -match 'Sorry')
  {Write-Host 'YES'}
  else
   {Write-Host 'NO'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that IE has been removed from Windows 11 and also that the COM object automation has been deprecated / broken.

[Powershell, InternetExplorer.Application and Windows 11 (deleted IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708684/powershell-internetexplorer-application-and-windows-11-deleted-ie)

> If you have an existing application that uses the InternetExplorer object to automate Internet Explorer 11, but the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application isn't available, your application won't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/#replace-internet-explorer-automation

Comment: O I see!     I downloaded the drivers, etc and tried a few scripts, but no luck.     Does anyone have a version of a POWERSHELL script for "screen scraping"   I could use as a model?

Comment: https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell